# Navigator.notification.alert message not working second time in iOS

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, jquery-mobile

I'm using iOS 6 in ios Navigator.notification.alert message not working :

- navigator.notification.alert message is coming 1st, but the navigator alert message is not coming for 2nd time...can any one know what the problem is and please tell me the solution.Thanks..

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: navigator.notification.alert(errmsg, this.alertDismissed,"","");

Comment: can you post the full code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue in Cordova 2.3.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1588?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=13575343#comment-13575343

You should upgrade to 2.4, I believe they have fixed it.